# Scheduled on the first Saturday of every month with Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to configure a job that runs at dawn on the first Saturday of every month through Cloud Scheduler.

Considering the Scheduler Job Frequency setting to be the first Saturday of every month, I have designated it as follows.

ex) `45 2 1-7 * 6`

However, it was confirmed that the above scheduler was running on the 23rd, last Saturday.

Is it not possible to configure a monthly schedule in Cloud Scheduler?
If you could give me an answer, I would be very grateful.

I have checked these [links](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?&_ga=2.269294646.-611583902.1633697926&_gac=1.88368745.1634533736.CjwKCAjwk6-LBhBZEiwAOUUDp8Ng_tatBELfrdv1B3pRdzBLqpw8NJWWb6RrmCpvSNmwfddXPGtgvRoCFFsQAvD_BwE#defining_the_job_schedule) in relation to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current schedule, `45 2 1-7 * 6`, reads as `At 02:45 on every day-of-month from 1 through 7 and on Saturday`. You can check it on [Crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#45_2_1-7_*_6).

In order to set a custom interval, you will need to use the [App Engine Cron format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#schedule_format).

In this case, try `first saturday of month 02:45`.